# How to replace a word in a textbox with another word

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing an article rewriter in VB.NET and I am having a problem in replacing some words with another word.
is there a way i can replace the words directly while the user is typing.
while texting it , i typed "**what is love, we always look at it**"
and it displayed **what is love we frequently look at it**
instead of

> what is affection we frequently see it

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged

    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("always") Then
        RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("always", "frequently")
    End If
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("love") Then
        RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("love", "affection")
    End If
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("look") Then
        RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("look", "see")
    End If 'RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: I am having a problem understanding what the problem is.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Why checking? You could call Replace directly - without checking.

Comment: Please how can i replace directly  without checking ?

Comment: People who have been here much much longer than you and know how the site works removed the language tag from your title for a reason - they are noise. Dont put them back in.  If you want to clarify the post to tell us **what the problem is**, that is fine - even advisable since it is vague as written.

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: "Replace directly without checking" means that it is NOT necessary to have the if conditions check to see if a word is present. If the word is not found by the `Replace` call, then nothing will change, the text will remain as-is. Other than that, what others want to know is **what is expected to happen (the problem), that does not appear to be working**?

Comment: `is it better` Not at all - **what is the problem**?  How does the code you have not work?  Note that it is probably a bad idea to do this while they are typing - if they are trying to type `have a lovely day!`  your code will try to change it to `have a affection day!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to change the text as it's being typed in.   You don't want to use the text changed event as it won't occur immediately on typing.  Use the keyup event instead.

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyUp
    Dim wordToFind As String = "findword"
    Dim replaceWord As String = "replaceword"
Richtextbox2.rtf = RichTextBox1.replace(wordToFind, replaceWord)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please give me a hint about the keyup event

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx.   In your case. You don't care what the key is...you are just checking and replacing text if it exists

Comment: i'm confused already  i am new to vb  i just started last month    please put me through a Little bit

Comment: Example above now

Comment: Jim was right...the previous response was not sufficient... hopefully the one now is more clear

Comment: you didn't put me through ...what is it meant to do ?  and remember i am assigning  the result to another Richtextbox

Comment: Changed the text again to update a second text box...that's easier...the keyup event fires immediately after typing on the text box...instead of updating text, you update rtf property so you don't lose styling.   This assumes a second text box is called richtextbox2